# AWS Ubuntu 13.04 and Websockets

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, websocket

I have launched an instance (Ubuntu Server 13.04 - ami-c30360aa (64-bit)) and I cannot get websockets working over port 80.

They work on other ports, such as 50000 or whatever I want -- however on port 80 I always receive:

"' failed: Unexpected response code: 400 "

Does anybody have any solutions?  I had them working on port 80 via Linux AMI on AWS, and on an older version of Ubuntu.

Comment: What's strange is that it will work when my desktop computer is accessing it via WiFi.  However, if my desktop computer is accessing it while being tethered to my iPhone it does NOT work.

Comment: That being said, it DOES work on other ports other than 80 when tethered to my iPhone.  Makes no sense.

Comment: It sounds like your iPhone or your carrier's network is intercepting data on port 80, and doesn't understand websockets. That's strange that the version of Ubuntu would matter though.